# Mockito chain of method calls

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

```
  @PostMapping("/node{id}/delete")
  public ResponseEntity<CallbackResponse> delete(@RequestParam("eventId") String eventId, @RequestParam("id") String nodeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

      serviceA.remove(eventId);
      client.getServiceB().deleteById(nodeId);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(new CallbackResponse(true), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I am new to unit testing.
please help me in writing test cases for above rest controller method

I tried below test but it's not working

```
    @Test
    public void testDeleteAgent() throws Exception{
        ServiceA serviceA = Mockito.mock(ServiceA.class);
        NodeClient client = Mockito.mock(NodeClient.class);

        Mockito.doNothing.when(serviceA).remove(Mockito.any());
        Mockito.doNothing.when(client.getServiceB()).deleteById(Mockito.any());
        ResponseEntity<CallbackResponse> result = agentController.delete("123", "456");
        Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), result.getStatusCode());
    }
```

when i run above test i am getting unfinished stubbing detected here error

I am created mock controller like this

```
    private ServiceA serviceA = Mockit.mock(ServiceA.class);
    private NodeClient client = Mockit.mock(NodeClient.class);
    private AgentController agentController = new Controller(serviceA, client);
```

Comment: Could you share what did you try and what problems you faced?

Comment: I added my code in the post

Comment: this code doesn't compile

Comment: i didn't added the full code

Comment: @RajuKmati brackets and semicolons are missing from what you added. Anyway add answer

Answer (score 1):

Supposing there is somewhere a `ServiceB` class, let's try

```
public class AgentController{

  @Inject
  private Client client;


  @PostMapping("/node{id}/delete")
  public ResponseEntity<CallbackResponse> delete(@RequestParam("eventId") String eventId, @RequestParam("id") String nodeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

      serviceA.remove(eventId);
      client.getServiceB().deleteById(nodeId);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(new CallbackResponse(true), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AgentControllerTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private AgentController agentController;

    @Mock
    private Client client;

    public void test(){
        ServiceB serviceB = Mockito.mock(ServiceB.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(serviceB).when(client).getServiceB();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(serviceB).deleteById(Mockito.any());

       // other here
    }

}
```

Comment: It's calling actual service method that's why i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Because, probably, the `client`  used in the test is not the mocked one you prepared; you have to inject mock object in your class under test

Comment: I added my mock controller code can you please tell me why it's not working